# How do add background color to google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

i am having google captcha in my application . Want to change border color of captcha

```
document.getElementsByClassName("rc-anchor-light")[0].setAttribute("style", "border-color: red;");
```

is the code which i am using . It works for some times but for some times it gives `Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined` error. However element with class name `rc-anchor-light` is in dom.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also .Captcha creates iframe internally inside which you can add color. First get captcha iframe which holds recaptcha.Then add border to this iframe and add color on it.

```
      var recaptchaframe = $('#googleCapatcha iframe');
        $($(recaptchaframe)[0]).attr('frameborder',1);
        $($(recaptchaframe)[0]).attr('style',"border-color:red;");
```